# Matplotlib plt object getting shared across plots

Tags: matplotlib

I have 2 functions , one plots a time series line, other plots the autocrrelation.

```
def plotacorr(dfasst):
    # Plot autocorrelation
    plt.acorr(dfasst, maxlags=3)
    # Add labels to autocorrelation plot
    plt.title('Autocorrelation of Asset Balances with previous Months Balances')
    plt.xlabel('Lag in Months')
    plt.ylabel('Autocorrelation')

    # Display the autocorrelation plot
    #plt.show()
    plt.savefig('C:/acorr_assets.jpeg')

def plottrend(df_acctsmry2):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fmt = '${x:,.0f}'
    tick = mtick.StrMethodFormatter(fmt)
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tick) 

    df_acctsmry2.plot(x='REPORTING_DATE',ax=ax,figsize=(20,12))
    plt.xticks(fontsize=20)
    plt.yticks(fontsize=20)
    plt.xlabel('REPORTING_DATE', fontsize=18)
    #plt.show()
    plt.savefig('C:/output.jpeg')
```

I first call plottrend, followed by plotacorr
But it seems that somehow the plt object is getting sharedbetween the 2 plots, so in the autocorrelation plot, I see the same result as plottrend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncomment the `plt.show()` on each function, that should do it (or call a `plt.show()` between the call to functions).

Comment: depends on what you mean by flush. It's more like a 'dump' statement. Whatever is in the plt handle gets displayed. Since you're not creating a second figure, the code overrides the existing one and should either display only the second plot or plot everything in the same figure. Another way to fix this would be to generate a second figure with plt.figure()